# How can we pass access token to the header in a Web View

Tags: ios, swift

let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)

webviewit!.load(myRequest)

Comment: welcome in SO world, as a beginner please explain your question as much as possible & show what u have done. 

Please see link for your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54781201/pass-token-through-url-into-webview-ios-swift .   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028516/passing-oauth-token-between-views-programmatically-in-swift

Answer (score 2):

See this code for pass header parameter value.

```
let weburl = URL(string: "http://yourURL")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: weburl! as URL)
request.setValue("HEADER_VALUE", forHTTPHeaderField:"HEADER_NAME")
myweb.load(request as URLRequest)
```

Comment: is it safe to send the token in header? Do you think it will be good if we use some kind of encryption to it.